# How to highlight tokens in react-syntax-highlighter?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a simulator, which shows the basic activities of a compiler. There is a tokenizer, to access each token in the program. And I want to highlight the token, currently active when the program is running.

I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter, to display the code aside with the simulator. How to highlight tokens separately, as needed, using this module?